# How to determine if Azure VM is VM Role (preview) or Virtual Machines (GA)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

The VM Role preview in Windows Azure ends on May 31, 2013 and Microsoft urges to migrate VM Roles to "proper" Virtual Machines that are in General Availability as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3dae01d2-2397-47ed-a134-f9ffe58a9b52.aspx

But how do I know which of the Virtual Machines running in Azure are VM Roles and which are Windows Azure Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a blog post that may help: Do I have VM Roles that I should migrate? at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2013/04/19/do-i-have-vm-roles-that-i-should-migrate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You probably see it easily in the portal, but an easy check could be to store something on your disk and stop/delete and recreate the machine.  If the file is no longer there, that means it's a VM role.
I also believe you cannot see VMRole in the new portal (and only in the old portal)